# How to use sed to extract only the date?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a directory with folders named '1','2',3'..  for which each is associated with 'date like' symlinks:

```
1 -> 2013-03-12
2 -> 2013-02-12
3 -> 2013-01-12
..
```

All I want to do is get into a variable the symlink name. so for example, in the example above I would have:

```
$LAST == "2013-01-13"
```

I am doing it all in a bash script and I was thinking of using `sed` combined with `ls`'s `--sort` option.

I don't seem to be able to extract just the date from ls.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: which date do you want to have?  the latest date? or the date with largest ln name? (1,2,3...) ? tell rule pls.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `readlink` :

> [readlink](http://explainshell.com/explain/1/readlink) - print resolved symbolic links or canonical file name

Below is a sample code that list all file in current directory (*cf.* `./*`) and read the target only of symlink (*cf.* `[[ -h $fn ]]`) into the `$LAST` variable.

#### Oneliner

```
for fn in ./*; do [[ -h $fn ]] && LAST="$(basename "$(readlink "$fn")")"; done
```

#### Script

```
for fn in ./*; do 
  if [[ -h $fn ]]; then
    LAST="$(basename "$(readlink "$fn")")"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

there is tool `readlink` for getting linked target name. E.g. `readlink *`

Your question is not very clear, I guess what you wanted might be first sort the `ls` output then take the last link target name. you could try:

```
ls -lc|awk -F'-> ' 'NF==2&&/-> ....-..-..$/{n=$NF}END{print n}'
```

this may not be the perfect solution because it depends on the ls output. also the regex checking for your "date-like" string is relatively loose, you can make it more strict if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can have

```
find dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/[0-9]+$' | sort -V | xargs -n 1 readlink
```

To get the last one:

```
readlink "$(find dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/[0-9]+$' | sort -V | tail -n 1)"
```

Optionally you can add `-type l`.

With Bash you can have this instead of `find`:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' dir/+([0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a linux expert.
Some of the answers I just didn't know how to modify to fit my needs.
This one is exactly what I needed:

```
LAST_DATE=`ls -l | sed -n 's/.*\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p' | sort -r | head -1`;
```